# number range rather than text vb.net

Tags: vb.net

so this is the code i came up with to delete a row in my excel sheet. It will work perfect for a line of text, but one of the columns contains numbers to two decimal places eg 2.31 3.65 1.01. how can i adapted the code so if a cell were to contain a number between 1.59 and 2.31 it would delete the row. Think i need to Dim an Integer just not sure were or what. many thanks

```
    Dim objExcel As Integer
    Dim objWorkbook As Object
    Dim objRange As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True

    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls")

    i = 1

    Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value = ""
        If objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value < "2" Then
            objRange = objExcel.Cells(i, 100).EntireRow
            objRange.Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I would change this line:

```
If objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value < "2" Then
```

to this:

```
If isNumeric(objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value) AndAlso _
    CDbl (objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value)>1.59 AndAlso _ 
    CDbl (objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value)<2.31 Then
```

For more Info, please see the [isNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx) and [CDbl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) functions at msdn.

Comment: this is great but it will only do one line

Comment: CDbl (objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value)>1.59 this will work but it wont move on to filter CDbl (objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value)<2.3 any ideas

Comment: It wont move because we have short circuit evaluation (See   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/817250 ) . Probably CDbl (objExcel.Cells(i, 4).Value) is not >1.59